# continuity of $\frac{1-\cos(x+y)}{x+y}$ for $(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Define $g$: $\Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ as

$g(x,y) = \frac{1-\cos(x+y)}{x+y}$ for $x+y$ not equal to $0$ and $g(0,0)$ = $\frac{1}{2}$ for $x+y = 0$

I need to check whether $g$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ or not.

I used the identity $1-\cos2x = 2\sin^2x$ and the fact that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ tends to $1$ as $x$ tends to $0$ to find limit of $g(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$ and then it is coming out to be $0$ which means it is not continuous at $0$.

On checking the answer, I saw it is given that it is continuous.

Please clarify

Comment: $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to 1$ when $x\to 0$

Comment: What is $g(x,-x)$ where $x\neq 0$?

Comment: You can use a backslash to indicate trig functions names are symbols, thus making them to display in upright typeface with appropriate spacing, not as a multiplication-like chain of variables: LaTeX/MathJax `\sin x` → $\sin x$ versus `sin x` → $sin x$.

Comment: Are you sure you copied this part: $\boxed{g(\color{red}{0,0}) = \frac{1}{2} \text{ for }x+ y = 0}$ correctly? The 'for' clause doesn't seem to make much sense if the equality is explicitly defined just for one point $(0,0)$....

Comment: I think that either there's an error in the book, or you forgot part of the formula, which should be $\dfrac{1-\cos(x+y)}{(x+y)^{\color{red}2}}$.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the function $g(x,y)$ for $x+y\not=0$ should be
$$\frac{1-\cos(x+y)}{(x+y)^2}$$
Since $\cos(t)=1-\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^2)$ as $t\to 0$, it follows that for $x+y\not=0$, as $(x+y)\to 0$ we have that
$$g(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}+o(1)$$
and therefore $g$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Of course also $\frac{1-\cos(x+y)}{x+y}$ can be extended to a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but in that case the assigned value over the line $x+y=0$ should be $0$.